# How vruntime of a newly created process initialised in CFS scheduler linux ?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cfs

In CFS scheduler, it always picks a process with minimum vruntime. vruntime of a running process is increased by the amount of CPU it consumes.

I have following two questions related to CFS and vruntime.

1. When multiple processes/threads are newly created, what is the initial vruntime of newly created process/thread ? Is the
   minimum vruntime in that ready queue at that time of creation or
   something else ?
2. If one process is there which has already ran for long and its vruntime is
   already high, in that scenario a new process is created. Now what will be the initial vruntime of newly created process ( keeping is mind the
   maximum unfairness ).